# colour edges by attribute graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph object, with black and white nodes. I want to colour the edges in the same way that I have specified line type.

First, I am not sure how I can reproduce an example on a multiplex graph - it is a network with two layers. I'm sorry, any guidance on reproducing large data sets welcome.

I would like to keep my nodes black and white, but I would like my edges to be black and red depending on their layer (1 or 2)

```
E(g)$color[E(g)$layer == '1'] <-'black'
E(g)$color[E(g)$layer == '2'] <-'red'

ggraph(g,layout = 'fr') + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(linetype = E(g)$layer),edge_colour = E(g)$color, edge_width = 0.5) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(fill = V(g)$Sex), shape=21, size = 3)+ theme_graph()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#FFFFFF"))
```

When I try and state colour as an edge attribute, I get an error message:

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10800): edge_colour

Also, when I replicate the Linetype argument inside the aes, the edges to change colour, but are blue and pinkish (not red and black)

geom_edge_link(aes(linetype = E(bpg16)$layer, edge_colour = E(bpg16)$layer), edge_width = 0.5)

I hope that makes sense,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing

```
  + scale_edge_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'red'))
```

where I could define values manually.